# Can I change the externalIP address of a Azure Fabric Cluster?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have a azure fabric cluster with a static IP address set up. Is there a way I can change the IP address of the cluster ?

Thanks.

Comment: Pretty sure you can just assign your LB a different public IP?

Answer (score 0):

if your cluster is consists of a single Primary Node type and has a Public load balancer attached to it, then it is as simple as what Madoxx has suggested

would suggest to modify the cluster with the template as opposed to via the Azure portal

if you have multiple Node types then it will be more complex